# Flask decorators not working together nicely

Tags: python, flask, decorator, python-decorators

I'm trying to use blueprints in a test Flask application, but I'm running into an strange issue. This is the relevant part of my code:

```
from functools import wraps
from flask import flash, redirect, render_template, \
request, session, url_for, Blueprint
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError
from datetime import datetime
from time import localtime, strftime

from .forms import AddAppointmentForm
from project import db
from project.models import Appointment

appointments_blueprint = Blueprint('appointments', __name__)

def login_required(test):
    @wraps(test)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        if 'logged_in' in session:
            return test(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            flash('You need to login first.')
            return redirect(url_for('users.login'))
        return wrap

@appointments_blueprint.route('/appointments/')
@login_required
def appointments():
    # Get current date
    current_datetime = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime())
    future_appointments = db.session.query(Appointment)\
        .filter(Appointment.due_date >= current_datetime)\
        .order_by(Appointment.due_date.asc())
    past_appointments = db.session.query(Appointment)\
        .filter(Appointment.due_date < current_datetime)\
        .order_by(Appointment.due_date.asc())
    return render_template('appointments.html',
        form = AddAppointmentForm(request.form),
        future_appointments=future_appointments,
        past_appointments=past_appointments)
```

Now when I run the app, I get this error:

```
  File "/home/mosquito/git/flask-scheduler/project/appointments/views.py", line 72, in <module>
    @login_required
  File "/home/mosquito/python_envs/flask-scheduler/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/blueprints.py", line 160, in decorator
    endpoint = options.pop("endpoint", f.__name__)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__name__'
```

Looking at blueprints.py, I see this:

```
def route(self, rule, **options):
    """Like :meth:`Flask.route` but for a blueprint.  The endpoint for the
    :func:`url_for` function is prefixed with the name of the blueprint.
    """
    def decorator(f):
        endpoint = options.pop("endpoint", f.__name__)
        self.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint, f, **options)
        return f
    return decorator
```

This fails because 'f' is None. Now even funnier, if I remove the

```
@login_required
```

decorator, when it reaches that point, f is a function, so that's OK.

In the other hand, if I remove the

```
@appointments_blueprint.route()
```

decorator, it works too. So it looks like the combination of both decorators is causing f to be None....any ideas what is going on here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to unindent the `return` line:

```
def login_required(test):
    @wraps(test)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        if 'logged_in' in session:
            return test(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            flash('You need to login first.')
            return redirect(url_for('users.login'))
    return wrap
```

You made it part of the `wrap` function itself, so the outer decorator function returned nothing.

Removing the `@appointments_blueprint.route()` simply doesn't register the route, so you never find out that you set `appointments` to `None`.